# How to scale with mirror modifier as if modifier was applied?

Tags: modeling, mirror, scale

From what I know the scaling action has changed since Blender 2.8 when editing while using an unapplied mirror modifier. I want my object to scale just like Image 1 (evenly towards the center from all 8 corners). Unfortunately, this only works with the full mesh and not when editing with an unapplied mirror modifier.

[image: Image 1]

If I use a mirror modifier (Image 2) the mesh only scales towards 1/4th of the full geometry.

[image: Image 2]

Turning on clipping doesn't help either, as then the Octagon scales into a square (Image 3).

[image: Image 3]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

1. Create a new project and remove default cube.
2. Press <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to set Top Orthographic view
3. Press <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>, then <kbd>M</kbd>, then <kbd>Y</kbd>, to add a cylinder

[image: 3]

4. Set Vertices to `8`.

[image: 4]

5. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to enter Edit Mode. Then Press <kbd>R</kbd>, and type `22.5`

[image: 5]

6. Press <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> to deselect all vertices

[image: 6]

7. Drag over the entire shape to select all vertices on top, then press <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>V</kbd> to delete them.
8. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select remaining vertices, then <kbd>I</kbd> and type `.2` to inset 20 cm (default radius should be 1 m)

[image: 8]

9. Press <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>F</kbd> to delete the inner face

[image: 9]

10. Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, click on the top (in this view) face, then right click to create a loop cut going through the middle of it.

[image: 10]

11. Repeat above step for the right face.

[image: 11]

12. Press <kbd>A</kbd>, to select all vertices, hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, and deselect all vertices in top-right quadrant (including those on edges of the quadrant)

[image: 12]

13. Press <kbd>X</kbd>, then <kbd>V</kbd> to remove these vertices.

[image: 13]

14. Press <kbd>TAB</kbd>, to go back to Object Mode.
15. Go to Modifier tab, and add a mirror modifier. Add **Y** to mirrored axes.

[image: 15]

16. Move your mouse over the viewport and press <kbd>TAB</kbd> to go to into edit mode again.
17. Press <kbd>A</kbd> to select all vertices, then change Transform Pivot Point from Median Point to 3D Cursor.

[image: 17]

18. If you moved the 3D cursor accidentally, realign it again, by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>W</kbd>

[image: 18]

19. Press <kbd>S</kbd> and scale the shape. It will keep its proportions.

[image: 19]

Comment: Thanks alot. Crucial for me was to select "Pivot around the 3d Cursor". With the cursor right, this did the job from where I was.